# Is there a way to populate with a projection in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a collection that contains a field that references documents from another collection like follows:

`ClassEnrollment`

```
_id | student | class
---------------------
```

and classes in the Class collection have the following schema:

```
_id | className | teacher | building | time | days | classNumber | description
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I have a set of 3000 classes I want to populate on the server I might do something like `ClassEnrollment.populate(listOfClassEnrollments, {path: 'class'});`

In my situation, I don't *want* the majority of the class fields though, just the name. If I get the list of 3000 classes from the db with all fields, I end up taking a performance hit in the form of network latency (these 3000 classes have to be transferred from the hosted db to the server, which might be 50 MB of raw data if the descriptions are long)

Is there a way to populate the list of class enrollments with just the name through an option to populate (behind the scenes I imagine it would work like a projection, so the db just responds with the class name and _id instead of all the class information)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `select` option in your [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) call to do this:

```
ClassEnrollment.populate(listOfClassEnrollments, {path: 'class', select: 'className'});
```

To specify multiple fields, use a space-separated list:

```
ClassEnrollment.populate(
    listOfClassEnrollments,
    {path: 'class', select: 'className classNumber'}
);
```

Comment: And if you want to select multiple, use space delimited:  `'className teacher building'`

Comment: What about multiple fields?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a very simple user & video schemas.

**1) USER SCHEMA**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

export default model("User", UserSchema);
```

**2) VIDEOS SCHEMA**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const { ObjectId } = Schema.Types;

const VideoSchema = new Schema({
  videoOwnerId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  desc: { type: String, required: true },
});

export default model("Video", VideoSchema);
```

Then I want to find in Videos Collection all videos by specific user AND at the same time all information about this user(a user document from Users Collection) and use projection on it ( select specific fields )

**3) Somewhere in our code (maybe in a controller)**

```
 const videos = await Video.find({ videoOwnerId: "someId214121" }).populate("videoOwnerId", "-password");
```

So to populate with projection you use a `populate("videoOwnerId", "-password")` method, when the first argument is a field you want to populate, the second argument is a projection.

- To get a document with all fields but without password for example

`populate("videoOwnerId", "-password")`

- To get only specific fields that you want(string with fields separated by whitespace)

`populate("videoOwnerId", "name email")`